# Accessing default camera on android with opencv & kivy

Tags: android, kivy, opencv, python

So this problem received some publicity, yet most answers provided address taking static images or filming the clip. However for my project I search for a way to do live processing. Whether the solution is a use of VideoCapture() or an ability to convert images to bytestrings without saving them.

Comment: Can you describe what you need to do? If you aren't committed to opencv there may be alternatives.

Comment: i want to make a portable app for HAAR cascade testing @inclement

Comment: but there is a workaround apparently. just remembered opencv can read from buffer. im sure textures can be tostringed. since ik resolution i can decode it back